# set label text to variable iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to do something that I thought would be easy but for some reason ( lack of experience ) it's not working. I am pulling some values out of a JSON response and set labels on my viewcontroller to the variables. When I step through and debug it the values are there but for some reason I cannot set any of the Labels to them or at least they are not showing up. HEre is the code for my Viewcontroller.

```
#import "VideoDetailViewController.h"
#import "VideoListViewController.h"
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
#import "VideoDetail.h"

@interface VideoDetailViewController ()

@property (readonly) NSString *api_username;
@property (readonly) NSString *api_password;
@property (readonly) NSString *nplays;

@end

@implementation VideoDetailViewController

@synthesize Plays;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = self.name.name;

    // Load the data on a background queue...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%s:%s@api.wistia.com/v1/stats/medias/c3e4797d8f.json", "api", "1b75e458de33a9b3f99d33f6bf409a7e145c570a"]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        // NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"play_count"]);
        NSNumber *_plays  = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"play_count"];
        _nplays = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:_plays numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

        // SET LABEL TO VALUE
        Plays.text = _nplays;
    }
    );

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

### EDIT

I set up the IBOutlet again correctly and still the label text is not changing. Even the NSLog check I set is saying the label text is the number I am setting it to but it's not changing in the label.

```
// NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"play_count"]);
    NSNumber *_plays  = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"play_count"];
    _nplays = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:_plays numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
    self.textEngagement.text = _nplays;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.textEngagement.text);
```

Comment: I do not see a property for `Plays`. Also, where is it instantiated? Have you made sure it is not nil when you were stepping through the code?

Comment: Is `Plays` an IBOutlet? Is it connected? How?

Comment: Plays is an IBOutlet in the header file :  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Plays;

Comment: and Its at the top of the .M file : @synthesize Plays;

Comment: Try ⌘+shift+K, then run your code again.

Comment: Can you set the label to a different string? e.g. `@"123";`

Comment: Nope, I am guessing that is the issue. I'm not accessing the text property of the Label at all it's not changing. Am I using the incorrect code I've tried self.textEngagement.text and _textEngagement.text and neither is working.

Comment: is viewDidLoad the correct place to be doing this or should it be in initWithNibName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set your label text on a background thread. 
You should not try to update UI on a background thread.
You need to go back to the main thread before updating the label value:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      self.textEngagement.text = _nplays;
});
```

Comment: That worked THANKS! I was banging my head on this for a day.... sucks to be a newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an IBOutlet to your label. The easiest way to do this is to open your interface in IB, then open an assistant editor and set it to automatic.  It might show your view controller's .m file or the .h file. Switch to the .h file if it the assistant editor doesn't take you there automatically. Then control-drag from your label into the area of your header with your other property declarations. That should let you create a new property. IB (Interface Builder) will add the correct code in your header, as well as connecting the outlet so it's active once your view controller's view loads.

In your case, you'd be setting up the property "play" (Following Objective-C naming conventions, it should be "play" with a lower-case "p", not "Play")

Comment: I went through and properly setup the IBOutlet and still the text in the label doesn't change. When I check it in NSLog it says the text for the label is set to the number I get from JSON, what could possibly be wrong? I'm thinking the code is incorrect or something.

Answer (score 0):

Either add an IBOutlet UILabel declaration in your header interface

```
@interface VideoDetailViewController ()
{
     IBOutlet UILabel *title;
}

@property (readonly) NSString *api_username;
@property (readonly) NSString *api_password;
@property (readonly) NSString *nplays;

@end
```

then wire the title object to the Label you created in Interface builder

OR

set a tag (i.e. 11) in your label's properies in IB (View section, underneath Mode) and

```
UILabel *name = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:11];
[name setText:self.name.name];
```

Comment: I went through all of these steps and the label text still isn't changing, even when I just set it to a random string it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting no where on this, the `UILabel` text won't change no matter where I try it or how many times I delete it and start over.